# Displaying in-app mobile push messages while app is in active use

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

Hi everyone

I would like to know if there's a way to send mobile push in-app messages that will appear instantly in the app screen without the need for the user to close the app and reopen it again.

According to the mobile push SDK documentation [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html) and [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html) this is not the default behavior of in-app messages sent from MC mobile push and mobile push in-app message can be loaded only when the app is in the background.

Is there a way or workaround to achieve that?

Many thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Any time a message is to be presented to the user you have the ability to implement an interface, capture the `messageId` and tell the SDK to show it at an appropriate time.  [Android IAM Docs](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html#optional-methods) and [iOS IAM Docs](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html)

Comment: Thanks Bill. Is it possible to achieve this on iOS as well? If yes - can you please provide the relevant link to do that? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the docs?? ;)